# python3.7 built-in exec() problem with unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x

suppose ex1.py contain:

```
 exec(open('ex2.py').read())
```

and ex2.py contain:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
class HelloWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.x = "وه شه نی گیان" #some Unicode words
        self.y = "قوربانه ت" #some Unicode words
        self.setWindowTitle(self.x)
        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.title = QLabel(self.y)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.title, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(gridLayout)
app = QApplication([])
mainWin = HelloWindow()
mainWin.resize(400,200)
mainWin.show()
app.exec_()
```

circumstance: windows 7 64bit, python 3.7.4, pyqt 5.12.2

opening cmd and running (python ex2.py) shows Unicode text in title and label correctly and it works fine; but running (python ex1.py), ruins encoding of texts.

using kivy instead of pyqt5 gives same result. I believe it's not pyqt5's bug,
both above methods in Ubuntu 18 work perfectly.

using import instead of exec solves the problem but I don't want that, because I have to import everything again in every scripts file, and I have plenty of them. can anyone tell me how to overcome this problem?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `exec` instead of importing a module?

Comment: As a note for the future -- it would be helpful to readers (and to other people with questions, trying to determine if they have the same problem and so if your question's answers are helpful to them) to include a concrete example of what "ruins encoding of texts" means in practice; if you get an exception, including its text is perfect; but a screenshot is better than nothing.

Comment: You should pass the encoding explicitly to `open` as a first step. But why are you doing this to begin with?

Comment: @chepner, I have too many scripts and windows and I didn't want to reimport modules in every scripts.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I have a login window, and after pushing a button, I want this window to be closed and new window to pop up, and I don't want to put all code lines in one file. the only way that came to my mind was using exec function. it works good in linux and thanks to all of you I know that it's good in windows too.

Comment: @ShoaibMirzaei no, I mean instead of `exec(open('ex2.py').read())` why don't you just do `import ex2`...?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have more than ten import commands in the code I wrote, if when going from one window to another I use <import ex2> instead of exec, then I should put all those import lines in the ex2.py file because the new GUI does not know about previously imported modules. I aslo have about 25 different GUIs, each of them inside a file, and user must be able to circulate between these windows on click. I really don't know which one is better. what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec(open('ex2.py', encoding='utf-8').read())`